# Use sweetalert2 in axios module errorHandler

Tags: vuejs2, axios, nuxt.js, sweetalert2

I am creating my first [nuxtjs](https://nuxtjs.org/) project and am using the [axios module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module) as my HTTP client.
**The Problem**
Use the [sweetalert2](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2) plugin within the axios module's [errorHandler](https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module#errorhandler).

---

**nuxt.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios'
  ],
  axios: {
    errorHandler (error) {
      if (process.browser) {
        const swal = require('sweetalert2')
        swal({
          title: 'Error', 
          text: 'Error', 
          confirmButtonColor: "#895CF2",
          confirmButtonText: 'Zurück',
          type: 'error'
        }).then(function () {
          window.history.back();
        })
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/sweetalert2', ssr: false }
  ],
  build: {
    vendor: ['axios', 'sweetalert2']
  }
}
```

**plugins/sweetalert2.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import swal from 'sweetalert2'

Vue.use(swal)
```

---

The errorHandler works without sweetalert and the sweetalert code works, as is in the frontend (pages/components).
I would be very thankful for any kind of help!

Comment: it could be nice to provide us the error message

Comment: Same error here. Did you solve it?

Comment: No. I never solved it.